# How to stop RMarkdown from generating huge knit / utf8 files

Tags: r, r-markdown

Rmarkdown is generating large files whenever I run chunks of my code. I initially thought that `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, message=FALSE)` caused the problem but the issue keeps recurring even after I deleted the line.

yaml header is pretty basic:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---
```

Options I used within the notebook are pretty basic, mostly fig.width and fig.height options. I am also running more than 30 nested models within the notebook so that could be the source of the problem now (not an issue before).

I'm also getting  `Error creating notebook: pandoc document conversion failed with error 251.`

How do I fix this? 
[image]

Comment: Are you knitting or running chunks of a notebook, or what? The reason they're big is because they contain your data in some form—an image of a plot, or a printed data frame or something—whereas the Rmd is just code. That doesn't really explain why they're there, though; unless you specify otherwise, usually the markdown gets deleted after pandoc runs and generates HTML or a PDF or whatever.

Comment: Without seeing your yaml header and options set within the doc (and perhaps arguments to the `render` call, if any), it's a bit of speculation. Can you provide that info?

Comment: I meant to say that this happens whenever I run chunks of the notebook, and it freezes up my laptop every time. I have also added my yaml header, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Just yaml header won't suffice. You probably need to create a **[mcve]**, i.e. script and data that we can run **just by copy-paste**.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, saving several images with fig.width and fig.height set to more than 10 generates huge images files/markdown files. I am no longer encountering the issue after deleting several image outputs.